# My cat does not eat if there is little food in the bowl but starts eating again if I fill up the bowl with more food

Tags: cats, behavior

I have noticed this strange behavior in my cat.

When I give her food in a bowl she stars eating but stops when there is a small amount of food still left. Then she keeps looking at me as if wanting more food. I point her to the food left in the bowl. She sniffs the food but doesn't eat it and again starts looking at me. She doesn't even stand up and keeps sitting in front of the bowl.

Now when I give her some more food, she again starts eating but stops when there is some amount of food left in the bowl. Again she starts looking at me as if she she wants some more food.

This process continues for 3 to 4 times until she has satisfied her hunger and then walks away.

Does anybody have any idea regarding the reason of this strange behavior?